# Does this kind of matrix have a special name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does this kind of $n\times n$ matrix $A = (A_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n = (a_{i} + a_{j})_{i,j=1}^n$ have a special name? Here $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ are real numbers.

Besides, could someone post any references for this kind of matrix? Many thanks!

Comment: You may also want to try math overflow.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Do you mean $[A]_{ij} = a_i+a_j$? If so, you can write $A=e^T a + a ^T e$, where $e=(1,...,1)^T$ and $a=(a_1,...,a_n)^T$.

Comment: Exactly. I mean $[A]_{ij} = a_i + a_j$.

Comment: @user10354138 sorry! didn't see the power of n, or the j=1. why are both sides raised to the power of n?

Comment: @SakethMalyala They are not, that is an index. See the immediate left of the section you've pointed out.

Comment: @asd i don't understand? could you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

If addition were multiplication the matrix you give would be a rank one matrix, $vv^{T}$, $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. But instead you just have a sum of a matrix with row vectors given as repetitions of a single vector with its transpose, and is thus of rank at most $2$. This suffices as a "name".

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply! Rank-2 matrix space should be much larger than the matrix space of such kind of $A$. A natural question is: what kind of rank-2 matrix can be written in the form of $A$?

Comment: The rank given in the answer above is not over the space of matrices, it is the actual rank as a linear operator. The second question is already answered in the comments above, and is just a rephrasing of what is posted in the above answer.

Comment: Thank you:) I get your point.